# Go back button in single-page webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I'm bulding my first WebApp. I've got a small navigation bar in the head where a back button should be placed. The Pages of the app are all placed in one document so the div's are set to

```
<div id="page_1" class="page" style="display:none">
```

and will be shown by clicking on a link

```
onclick="show('Page_dash');
```

Now i want to have a back button which goes back to the last shown page. I've tried this

```
onclick="history.go(-1);
```

but it's not working because there is only one page which contains all pages so the history.go(-1) goes to the last visited homepage. So i'm looking for a good, fast and simple solution!

thanks

Comment: you should use the history api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: well this did not work for me because the pages are not displayed. If i use history.back() or history.go(-1) nothing happens

Comment: You can also append entries to the history using the API mentioned above without displaying anything. Please read that MDN article again and follow the example links…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create an effective single page application (SPA), you will need to implement a method to track history that appears traditional to your end users.  There are a few different techniques for this, but as a developer of enterprise-level single page applications, I highly recommend using the **url hash** method.

This technique allows your end users to bookmark specific "pages" in your single page app, along with using their browser's back button to return to the previous page.  End users can become extremely frustrated with a single page app if they try to return to the previous page using their browser's back button, and find that they are returned to Google, or whatever site they visited before yours.

Here is some additional reading on the subject:  [URL Hash Techniques](http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2011/10/must-know-url-hashtechniques-for-ajax-applications/)